# ¿Como poner horas en control Datepicker WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

necesito que pueda escoger el dia y la hora pero creo que no es compatible con las horas o se puede cambiar el formato?

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpFirst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="430,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayDate="2018-06-18" SelectedDateFormat="Short"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes mirar la extensión [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker)

He probado a no usar la extensión y consigo que se vea la hora, pero no puedo seleccionarla por lo que siempre te pone las 00:00. 
Te dejo el código por si te puede ayudar:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpFirst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayDate="2018-06-18"  SelectedDateFormat="Short" Width="181">
        <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
            </DatePicker.Resources>
    </DatePicker>
```

Un saludo

Comment: DateTimePicker se puede instalar de nuget y gratis?

Comment: Gratis sí ya que esta en github y solo tendrías que bajar la dll. En cuanto a si está en el nuget no lo sé la verdad.

Comment: cual "dll" ocupo solo encuentro soluciones

Comment: Cabe señalar que tal como indica el nombre del control, solo es para fecha, pero como bien dice Gerardo la solución más rápida y fácil es integrar una librería externa, como la que viene con el WPF Toolkit que es la que te comenta él, aunque hay varias más, otra solución es crear tu propio control personalizado, que no es tan difícil.

Comment: @LuisAcosta te dejo el enlace con la wiki del proyecto. Hay puedes ver como se instala y por lo que veo si puedes usar el nuget : https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki